# handling click on button inside item of recycler listview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Following is my code where I want to add one on clicking BtnAdd and reduce the count by clicking BtnSub but I can't find a way to handle event on button and hence update the count..

I looked for 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html

but this gives click on whole item. I need to handle on item inside row item of recycler view.

Please suggest if there is any method to achieve this.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ItemHolder>{

   private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_layout, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        ItemHolder orderObjectHolder = new ItemHolder(view);
        return orderObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item item = items.get(position);
        holder.countText.setText("");
        holder.currentItem = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public Item currentItem;
        TextView countText;
        Button AddBtn, SubBtn;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            countText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_name);

            AddBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_service1_btn_add);
            SubBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_service1_btn_sub);

            AddBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            SubBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i){
         myViewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(i));
          myViewHolder.btnButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /// button click event
            }
        });
    }
```